# Soap/Rest request over MQ

Tags: soap, ibm-mq

I have got a task to send SOAP request from source A to destination B.

But the problem is Source A is not ready until some time so I would send the request mimicking as if source A to Destination B. The actual problem I have is that IBM MQ is the transport layer being used to send from A to B.

How can I achieve sending SOAP request onto MQ client and it delivers across the destination B.

- Do we need specialized tool to put SOAP message onto MQ? If so which are those tool's.
- Do I need to install any MQ client onto my local machine and point it towards destination B MQ client?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Currently your question reads like a request for a tool recomendation and does not demonstrate what you have tried.  So will probably be closed as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the SOAP JMS transport, with MQ as the JMS provider.  You can either use client connections to an MQ queue manager, or use server connections.

But either way, you need to use JMS to conform to the SOAP standard.